# How to structure the for loop to give me the correct output? List generated is longer than it should be

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter-notebook, iterator

I have two lists (`tb_shade` and `tb_sun`) that I'm trying to iterate through and append a `1` to a third list (`activity_status`) if a criterion is met or a `0` if not. The  `tb_shade` and `tb_sun` lists are the same length (8760). And I'm trying to create a third list (`activity_status`) that is also the same length, and that has a value of `0` if either of the values of `tb_shade` or `tb_sun` lists is outside of the numeric range: 29-39, or an `1` if either values are within that range. I've tried it a couple different ways. I've included two of those attempts below. Neither one works.

The first try appends `0` for all rows in the list even though I know the criteria are met at some times. The second try has an output `activity_status` list that is 122268322 values long. It should be the same as the `tb_sun` and `tb_shade` lists which are both 8760. Does anyone know how to get this to run? Any helps or tip would be appreciated! Thanks!

First try

```
activity_status=[]    
for i,q in zip(tb_shade, tb_sun):
    if tb_shade[i] > (39) or tb_sun[q] < (29):
        activity_status.append(0)
    else:
        activity_status.append(1)
```

Second try

```
    
activity_status=[]    
for i in range(len(tb_shade)):
    for q in range(len(tb_sun)):
        if tb_shade[i] > 39 or tb_sun[q] < 29:
            activity_status.append(0)
        if tb_shade[i] < 39 or tb_sun[q] > 29:
            activity_status.append(1)
print(len(activity_status)) #122268322
print(len(tb_shade)) #8760
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second try is almost correct. You have nested for loops so what you're actually doing is looping over tb_sun 8760 times and comparing every value in each array with each other. Try this:

```
activity_status=[]    
for i in range(len(tb_shade)):
    
    if tb_shade[i] > 39 or tb_sun[i] < 29:
        activity_status.append(0)
    if tb_shade[i] < 39 or tb_sun[i] > 29:
        activity_status.append(1)

print(len(activity_status))
print(len(tb_shade))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help here! Although when I run your code the ```activity_status``` list has a length of ```15400``` instead of ```8760```  and I'm not sure why

Comment: My bad. Use elif instead of if on the second if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an iteration with in an iteration and this is giving you the square of the result you are expecting.
i.e instead of counting just from 0 to 8759, it is looping from 0 to 8759 for 8760 times.

Instead, you can use one for loop and use that for iterating both lists.

Second, your criteria is not mutually exclusive from what you have written. For example, if the two numbers from tb_shade and tb_sun are 30 and 50 respectively, both if clauses are met and they both will execute. Assuming you are trying to check if the numbers in both cases is between 29 and 39, I have made some changes to your code.

```
activity_status=[]    
for i in range(len(tb_shade)):
    if tb_shade[i]>29 and tb_shade[i]<39 and tb_sun[i]>29 and tb_sun[i]<39:
        activity_status.append(1)
    else:
        activity_status.append(0)

print(len(activity_status)) #should give 8760 if both lists are of length 8760
print(len(tb_shade)) #8760
```

Comment: Thanks for this response Siem! This code works but I'm slightly unsure if it is giving me what I want... I am trying to get a ```1``` appended to the ```activity_status``` list if either the shade or sun number is between 29-39, but I don't need both of those numbers to be in the range. I think your code is written so that only a 1 is appended if both numbers are in that range, right?

Comment: Yes the code is checking if both numbers are in that range. If you want to check if either one is in that range you can replace the second "and" in the third line with "or".

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension, the item is 1 if the values of in table tb_shade and tb_sun are within the range [29, 39]. Otherwise, the item is 0.

```
activity_status = [1 if (29 <= shade <= 39 and 29 <= sun <= 39) else 0 for shade, sun in zip(tb_shade, tb_sun)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pramote! I changed your code to ```activity_status = [1 if (29 <= shade <= 39 or 29 <= sun <= 39) else 0 for shade, sun in zip(tb_shade, tb_sun)]``` and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Adding some explanation to this code would dramatically improve the quality of this answer. See [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)